# eslint Parsing error: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, class-fields

Why is eslint throwing this error? The Javascript runs without issue inside of React Native. The code was taken from the react-navigation example at : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

Javascript:

```
static navigationOptions = { header: null };
```

eslint error:

```
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

.eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": "standard",
    "plugins": [
      "react",
      "react-native"
    ]
};
```

Comment: Is your eslint configured for ES6?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The syntax is not yet standardised, but a stage-2 proposal for inclusion in Javascript (see "Class Fields" on https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

Try adding the following option above "extends" in your .eslintrc.js:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
```

Comment: [babel-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint) is now deprecated - use [@babel/eslint-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/eslint-parser) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I get this error out of blue for the code that worked previously, so I know it's not a syntax error. Restarting VSCode solves my issue.