# React: Parsing error in my functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I installed babel-eslint and added `"parser": "babel-eslint"` but I'm still getting parsing error.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "listassign",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {

    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3"
  },
  "extends": [
    "standard",
    "standard-react"
]

}
```

I'm getting error in file:

```js
function CharComponent(props){

    let displayList = [];

    function delete(e){
        let index = e.target.id;
        displayList.slice(index,1);
    }
```

Error is:`Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'delete'`

I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626825/10390678) but no help.

Comment: `delete` is a keyword in JavaScript. You cannot use it as a function/variable name.

Comment: damnn @Pointy silly me !!!!!!! You helped me from wasting another hour to solve this, thanks!

Comment: Reserved keyword as a property name ([dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306315/browser-support-for-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-property-name-in-javascript)) is unrelated to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to rename your function to something other than `delete`. Because `delete` is [a keyword used by JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), it is not a valid function name.

Try naming it something like

```
function deleteItem(e){
    let index = e.target.id;
    displayList.slice(index,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use delete as a keyword since it is a javascript keyword! Rename your function and it should work fine.